# SSMS add-in to set scripting options

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, add-in, ssms

In an SSMS add-in, the following code will toggle the fontsize of the text editor window between 10 and 22:

```
Properties props_texteditor = _addInInstance.DTE.Properties["FontsAndColors", "TextEditor"];
Property propFontSize = props_texteditor.Item(3); //"FontSize"
propFontSize.Value = ((Int16)propFontSize.Value == 10 ? 22 : 10);
```

Not particularly useful, but it demonstrates that my add-in can set an SSMS Tools/Options property, in this case using the category/page names "FontsAndColors", "TextEditor".

What I actually want my add-in to do is set the scripting option "Include IF NOT EXISTS clause" to true or false, but I can't find any documentation on it. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at SSMSBoost add-in, that I develop. I have implemented custom scripting options there.

If you want to experiment yourself, have a look at these objects:
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UserSettings.ScriptingOptions
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter

Comment: That looks very interesting indeed. But unfortunately none of it does what I need for this particular requirement. I need to set the scripting option that will take effect during the standard SSMS  scripting from Object Browser, like my Font example does. Thanks.